# Symfony2 non mapped collectionType not working

Tags: jquery, symfony, collections, multiple-file-upload

I am using the method explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) to implement multiple file upload, but it can't find a way to make it work. I know there is already a lot of questions about it, but I couldn't find a suitable answer for my case.

Note that I am storing file's content in the database, thanks to a file Entity with Name, Content and Type attributes. 
However in order to make it work, I am not mapping the form to this entity.

So, my controller looks like this :

```
    $files = [];

    $form = $this->createForm(MultipleFilesType::class, []);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $files = $form->getData();

        dump($files);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            //code that stores the file in the database which works fine and is not relevant to my problems I think
        }
        return // redirect to some page
    }

    return //form to the view
```

My MultipleFilesType is the collection which embed multiple addFileType :

```
class MultipleFilesType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('files', CollectionType::class, array (
            'entry_type' => addFileType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'data' => array(
               array ('file' => null)
            )
        ))
    ;
}
}
```

and my addFileType is this :

```
class AddFileType extends AbstractType
{


/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file', FileType::class, array (
            'label' => false
        ))
    ;

}
}
```

In my view I can add / remove fields thanks to some JQuery explained in the linked documentation. (The code is more or less the same as the one in the doc, except that I am not working with Entites, so I am not showing it here).

I first tried to do single file uploads, which worked nicely, and then I tried the above code, using the collectionType and a $files array to retrieve the data from the form to the controller, but I am having these issues :

When I submit the form, apparently the values of files after the first one are not valid.

When I submit only one file (no validation error), the dump($files) in the controller show me an empty array no matter what.

Any help would be appreciated =) Don't hesitate to ask for more code if you think it is needed.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$files = $form->getData();
```

it was

```
$files = $form->get("files")->getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

`AddFileType` is useless and breaks your Form mapping. Use directly `FileType` in your `MultipleFileType`.

Then, for your other mistakes, it mainly depends on your JavaScript and your entities.

Client-side, you need to submit each file with the name "multiple_file_form[files][INDEX]" where INDEX is the index of each file in the list. To do that:

- If you submit synchronously (using Submit button and `form` tag), have `<input type="file" name="multiple_files_form[files][INDEX]">` input tags
- If your form is submitted asynchronously (through AJAX), your request parameters must be an array like this:

  ```
  {
       "multiple_files_form": {
           "files": [
               // Your files here...
           ]
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: For now my input files have the name "multiple_files[files][INDEX]". Is it why my $files array in my controller is empty ? 
Should I just change those name with some javascript to add the "_form" which is missing ?
Also I realise that my AddFileType is useless in his current state, but I don't really understand how using it instead or FileType would result in mistakes :/

Comment: Yes it may definitely be the reason $data is empty, there might be another reason but this seems a good one. AddFileType could result in mistakes because you add a level of nesting in expected data array. With AddFileType, you would need to submit inputs with "multiple_files_form[files][INDEX][file]"

Comment: So, I did this change. When my names are `"multiple_files_form[files][INDEX]"` it doesn't work either. The controller doesn't go into the  `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` condition anymore when I submit the form.

Comment: I think your explanations about the input names are correct except for the `_form` part, but I can't find a find to check this.Without this I can now submit my form with as many input as I want, but when I try to retrieve the data in my controller, the array is always empty. 
At least I managed to get rid of the submission errors.